# Difference in GoogleMaps rendering

Tags: codenameone

I have noticed some difference in the google maps simulator and on-device rendering of googlemaps. Going through the beatiful featured apps like Travel2gether and Paltel app, are the maps used in this apps native because I noticed they come with the + - sign and they even show more places mapped wheres on the normal GoogleMapComponent those places don't show.

Any clarifications for this?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paltel uses native maps which you can install via the [extensions menu](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/automatically-install-update-distribute-cn1libs-extensions.html).
You can read about using it [here](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/).

Travel2gether uses the old maps with the Google provider instead of open street maps.

Each has its advantages/limits but we are slowly gravitating towards the native maps approach which is probably a better choice.